# Print and submit data into Database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form. I would like to print what user intputing in this form and insert data into database. But I 'm facing problem:

1. If I print data in present window, printing is OK, but don't insert into database. Had a error: `Form submission canceled because the form is not connected`
2. If I print data in new window, insert database is ok, but don't print user's data.

I have researched two days, but haven't found any resolve.
I used MVC 1 module and 1 template, and use javascript (jqwery)

Example as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name ="form"  method="post" action="index.php?controller=index&action=add" onsubmit="return submitData()">
        <input type="text" id = "content" name="content">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitData() {
        // print data
        content = '<p>The content is: ' + document.getElementById("content").value + '</p>';
        document.body.innerHTML = content;
        window.print();

        // submit data
        return true;
    }    
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the code where you insert into the database?

Comment: Base on `controller=index&action=add"` will have action insert into database. The code insert database is OK, The software will return true don't wait `window.print()` show printing screen => User don't print => this is problem

Comment: I would like to show printing screen showed and user press print button then  `submitData() ` return true